# Adding up the TOTAL number of XML Items with PHP

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I am trying to get the **total** number of bikes available in a bike share system. I am using php and simpleXML to filter [the XML data](https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml).

I have successfully retrieved the number of bikes at *each* station.

```
foreach ($xml->station as $items) {
print $items->nbBikes;
}
```

But I want the **total number** of bikes available at all stations. I tried this to declare a variable ($totalBikes) that added to itself each time through the foreach statement, but it did not work.

```
foreach ($xml->station as $items) {
print $items->nbBikes;

    $numberOfBikes = $items->nbBikes;   
    $totalBikes= $numberOfBikes += $numberOfBikes;

}

 print $totalBikes;
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to get the total number of bikes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to add $numberofbikes to $totalbikes, not to itself:

```
$totalBikes += $numberOfBikes;
```

which is a shortcut version of

```
$totalBikes = $totalbikes + $numberOfBikes;
```

Be sure you're declaring '$totalbikes' before your foreach loop though so it doesn't get reset on each iteration.

Comment: Hopefully this restores what you were looking for from the original.

Answer (score 0):

You declared $totalBikes within the loop, so it is getting reset every time you iterate. Also, you're not adding $numberOfBikes to $totalBikes properly. Try this:

```
$totalBikes = 0;
foreach ($xml->station as $items) {
    $numberOfBikes = $items->nbBikes;
    $totalBikes += $numberOfBikes;
}
print $totalBikes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating, use `xpath`:

```
$bikes = $xml->xpath("/stations/station/nbBikes");
$sum = array_sum(array_map("intval", $bikes));
```

`line 1` will select all `<nbBikes>` into an array, but as `SimpleXml` objects
`line 2` will first transform all elements to `Integer`, then add them up.

Note: For a one-liner, there's a `sum`-function in `xpath`, but I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas why?

```
$sum = $xml->xpath("sum(/stations/station/nbBikes)")[0];
```